# Does Custom google search work for https sites or not?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

i have implemented the custom google search for my website and my website is on **https** protocol.
i have already done all settings but custom google search is not working.

**Someone please tell me if custom google search work for https sites or not?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google Custom Search on https to avoid non secure content prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838716/how-to-use-google-custom-search-on-https-to-avoid-non-secure-content-prompt)